# Properly invoking PowerShell.exe from cmd.exe - -File, double-quotes, and single-quotes

Tags: powershell, cmd

Let's say I have the following simple PowerShell script in `c:\temp\file-data-alt.ps1`:

```
Param ($filename, $data)

Write-Output ($filename)
Write-Output ($data)
```

If I invoke it from `cmd.exe` as follows I get the expected output:

```
C:\Temp>PowerShell.exe -File c:\temp\file-data-alt.ps1 -Filename "c:\abc bcd cde" -Data "123 234 345"
c:\abc bcd cde
123 234 345
```

If I remove `-File`, we get unexpected results:

```
C:\Temp>PowerShell.exe c:\temp\file-data-alt.ps1 -Filename "c:\abc bcd cde" -Data "123 234 345"
c:\abc
123
```

If I leave off `-File` but switch the double-quotes to single-quotes, it appears to work:

```
C:\Temp>PowerShell.exe c:\temp\file-data-alt.ps1 -Filename 'c:\abc bcd cde' -Data '123 234 345'
c:\abc bcd cde
123 234 345
```

And, now, if we add `-File` back in, we get unexpected results:

```
C:\Temp>PowerShell.exe -File c:\temp\file-data-alt.ps1 -Filename 'c:\abc bcd cde' -Data '123 234 345'
'c:\abc
'123
```

I'm assuming that the first approach (`-File` with double-quotes) is the proper approach. Is this the case?

It *seems* to kinda work when you leave `-File` off especially if you use single-quotes. Clearly, leaving off `-File` has some sort of function. When would you want to take that approach? Is there a legitimate use case for leaving `-File` off?

Comment: The -Command parameter is used if you don’t specify -File